# Get first and last visible line from other buffer than current

Tags: vimscript, buffers

I know that I can get the first and last visible lines in the current buffer by using `line('w0')` and `line('w$')`, but is there a way to do it for other buffers that are visible but not active as well?

For example if I have a split window, left is buffer number `3` (current), and right is buffer number `4`. How to get first and last visible lines for buffer `4` without moving the cursor there **in vimscript**?

Answer (score 4):

In Neovim you can't. In Vim it's trivial:

```
echo line('w0', winid)
```

Note that you have to provide window ID, not simply buffer ID.

Comment: I was checking `he: line()` on neovim and there is no extra param indeed...

Comment: Introduced in [8.1.1967](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1967).  Similarly, `getcurpos()` supports an optional `winid` argument since [8.2.1727](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.1727).

Comment: @Matt do you of any alternatives to `line()` that would work in neovim as well?

Comment: @skamsie Neovim still lacks `win_execute()` and such. So currently the only way is `win_gotoid()` and back.

Comment: @Matt weirdly enough, on Neovim, on line 619 of `:he usr_41.txt` I can see `win_execute()` listed, but it does not work when you try to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the answer from @Matt is the obvious solution for **vim**, I needed something that will work in **neovim** as well, so I ended up writing a function that works in both editors.

```
function! GetVisibleLines()
  let l:visible_w = gettabinfo(tabpagenr())[0]['windows']
  let l:current_w = win_getid()
  let l:visible_l = []

  for w in l:visible_w
    noautocmd call win_gotoid(w)
    call add(
          \ l:visible_l,
          \ {'win': w,
          \  'buf': getwininfo(w)[0]['bufnr'],
          \  'lines': [line('w0'), line('w$')]})
  endfor

  noautocmd call win_gotoid(l:current_w)
  return l:visible_l
endfunction
```

It returns a list with an item for each visible window for the current tab containing the window id, the buffer and the visible lines (first and last)

**Example**

```
:echo GetVisibleLines()
-----------------------

[ 
  {'buf': 4, 'win': 1015, 'lines': [1, 25]},
  {'buf': 4, 'win': 1001, 'lines': [418, 441]},
  {'buf': 2, 'win': 1000, 'lines': [1, 12]}
]
```

Comment: There is also the option with lua to call `vim.api.nvim_win_call(winid, function() return {vim.fn.line('w0'), vim.fn.line('w$')} end)`